# add values to session variable in php

Tags: php, variables, session, session-variables

I'm trying to add a variable quantity in a $_SESSION variable and i don't know how to do it
here is my code:

```
$cantidad=$_POST['cantidad'];
$ver=$_SESSION['carro'][$id_producto];

    $ncantidad=$ver+$cantidad;

    echo $ncantidad;
    $_SESSION['carro'][$id_producto][$ncantidad];
```

In here cantidad is how many products of the same kind i want, then I try to add the actual number of product to the new one and then store it in the same variable

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to assign your quantity to the session variable you prefer, i used `quantity` as last key, you might want to change it

```
$_SESSION['carro'][$id_producto]['quantity'] = $ncantidad;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should wrote it like this:

```
$_SESSION['carro'][$id_producto]+=$ncantidad;

// echo $_SESSION['carro'][$id_producto];
```

see [php session](http://www.w3schools.com/Php/php_sessions.asp) for further reading